# Media-queries not working newsletter letter template

Tags: css

I have set body background color using media query but Media query not working my newsletter template design. could you please solve this issue.

sample html:

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .body1{background: red!important;}
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="body1" style="border:none !important;background: #e4e3e3;">
 <tr>
  <td style="border:none !important;padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<h1>Welcome Zeeapp</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @VahidAkhtar - He's talking about email template

Comment: media queries are not supported in every client: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/media-queries-in-html-email/ (scroll down for a list)

Comment: thanks for qucik response, Yes talking about email template

Comment: all browser working fine but inside of gmail app not working media queries.

Answer (score 1):

use below css just remove the in-line css of table and add below code

```
<style type="text/css">
     @media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
            .body1{background: red;}
}
table{
     border:none ; background: #e4e3e3; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: _“you are using body as class and this is a wrong method”_ - their `table` element has `class="body1"`, if you look closely. One might argue over that choice of class _name_, but it is not actually “wrong”, if the background of that table is what they are trying to set here.

Comment: So other than that you changed the breakpoint width, and removed the !important, it is still what they already had. So how is that supposed to fix the issue?

Comment: due to inline css table take background:#e4e3e3 on width of 600px so we have to remove the inline css and add in to style tag so it will work properly